# <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera"> displays tiny thumbnail - can this be enlarged

Tags: html, intel-xdk, image-capture

Creating an App using Intel XDK and in it capturing an image using the line;

```
<input id="upload-form-file" name="userfile" size="300" value="Take a Picture" type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

This works fine - and my subsequent upload gets the picture fine - but on taking this displays just a tiny thumbnail picture.

Is this thumbnail accessible to be CSS'd - or to be enlarged in some way? The size doesn't have any effect on it...

Have looked at the spec' of Input; found loads of examples of getting at the pic and moving it somewhere else, but all I want is that thumbnail to enlarge

Thanks